# ReactJS: manage radiobutton behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form in which there are two radio button one for Gratis on for Pay.
I should manage the answer. So if the user click on :

```
Gratis: Yes --> Pay: No. 
Gratis: No ---> Pay: Yes
Pay: Yes ---> Gratis: No.
Pay: No ---> Gratis: Yes



if(Gratis == "true" && Pay !== undefined){
    questionnaire.SelfCertification.Pay = "false"
  }
  if(Gratis == "true" && Pay === undefined){
    Pay = "false"
  }
  if(Gratis == "false" && Pay !== undefined){
    Pay = "true"
  }
  if(Gratis == "false" && Pay === undefined){
    Pay = "true"
  }
  if(Pay == "true" && Gratis === undefined){
    Gratis = "false"
  }
  if(Pay == "false" && Gratis === undefined){
    Gratis = "true"
  }
```

I have tried to do in this way, but there are some cases that didn't work properly, like the case:

if I select

```
Pay: Yes --> Gratis: No (and this is ok), 
//but if now i select 
Pay: No --> Gratis: No ( and it should go to Yes).
```

How can I do?

Comment: Seems a simple boolean state should capture this "binary state". Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this component?

Comment: What do you mean with capture this "binary state"?

Comment: The option is either "Gratis" or "Pay". You are toggling between the two. Binary.... two options. Select one, deselect the other. If you put them in a radio button group and provide one initially selected you'll get the "binary" behavior for free as only 1 radio option in a group can be "selected".

Comment: And without the possibility of having one selected initially is not possible?

Comment: No, it would still work the same, but it seems you implied there would always be a selected one.

Comment: When the form is initialized, no default value is selected, but in the end if one value is selected the other must always be different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a radio group for these two (or even more) radio inputs and toggle between them. Here's a very trivial example.

```
const [gratisPay, setGratisPay] = useState("Gratis");

const changeHandler = (e) => {
  // e.target.value is the radio input value
  // do what you need, like update some state
  setGratisPay(e.target.value);
};

...

<form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
  <label>
    Gratis
    <input
      type="radio"
      value="Gratis"
      name="gratisPay"
      checked={gratisPay === 'Gratis'}
      onChange={changeHandler}
      />
  </label>
  <label>
    Pay
    <input
      type="radio"
      value="Pay"
      name="gratisPay"
      checked={gratisPay === 'Pay'}
      onChange={changeHandler}
    />
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Submitting the form simply logs the radio group value.

## Demo

[image: Edit reactjs-manage-radiobutton-behavior]